# F# windows phone isolated storage and XML

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, f#, isolatedstoragefile

I have a WP7 app that tracks a user's location. All is working fine, except I would like to write the locations to isolated storage on the position changed event of the GeoCoordinate watcher, and I keep getting the "Operation Not Permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" message. Can anyone help getting this to work?

The member to save the coordinates to file is:

```
let xname n = XName.op_Implicit(n)
let xdoc (el: seq<XElement>) = new XDocument(Array.map box (Array.ofSeq el))
let xelem s el = new XElement(xname s, box el)
let xstr s = box s


member this.createLocationsFile latitude longitude =
   try
                let doc : XDocument =
                        xdoc
                            [xelem "root"
                                [xelem "location"
                                    [(xelem "latitude" (xstr latitude))
                                     (xelem "longitude" (xstr longitude))
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]                    
                use store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()                   
                if not (store.FileExists("locations.xml")) then
                     let file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("locations.xml", IO.FileMode.Create, store)                   
                     doc.Save(file)
                else
                    let file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("locations.xml", IO.FileMode.Open, store)
                    let docAmended : XDocument = XDocument.Load(file)
                    let elementToAdd =
                        docAmended.Element(xname "root").Add(
                            [xelem "location"
                                [(xelem "latitude" (xstr latitude))
                                 (xelem "longitude" (xstr longitude))
                                ]
                            ])
                    docAmended.Save(file)
    with
        | :? IsolatedStorageException as ex -> MessageBox.Show("Error saving file: " + ex.Message) |> ignore
            | _ -> MessageBox.Show("Unable to open file") |> ignore
```

And the PositionChangedEventHandler is:

```
let MyPositionChanged(e : GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>, map : Map, ellipse : Ellipse) =
    let ppLoc = new GeoCoordinate(e.Position.Location.Latitude, e.Position.Location.Longitude)
    map.SetView(ppLoc, 10.0)
    //do layer.AddChild(ellipse, ppLoc)
    ellipse.Visibility <- System.Windows.Visibility.Visible
    let iso = new IsolatedStorageHelper()
    let lat = ppLoc.Latitude.ToString()
    let lon = ppLoc.Longitude.ToString()
    do iso.createLocationsFile lat lon
```

Comment: The error sounds like something is holding the file in isolated storage. See if you can dispose of the handles to the file in your if and else cases in the createLocationsFile  event. Unfortunately, I am not an F#er, sorry, but that's what I'd be checking for in C# code.

Comment: You didn't dispose `IsolatedStorageFileStream` instances. Try to replace `let file = ...` by `use file = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I am not an F#er, but I have seen this error a couple of times with C#. The "using" block solved it nicely. Even though you are using a "use" block, the docs say that it is better to use "using" block for things like that, because it sounds like "locations.xml" is still open by something.

Try the word "using" instead of "use" when you run the following code:

```
            ...
            ]                    
            use store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()                   
            if not (store.FileExists("locations.xml")) then
            ...
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233240%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Here is the important highlight as to why (from the link above):

The using function and the use binding are nearly equivalent ways to accomplish the same thing. The using keyword provides more control over when Dispose is called. When you use using, Dispose is called at the end of the function or lambda expression; when you use the use keyword, Dispose is called at the end of the containing code block. In general, you should prefer to use use instead of the using function.

Comment: well I tried your suggestion on the 'use' instead of 'let', I have now created the file, but am getting an error in that the application can't open the file. I've checked IsolatedStorage and sure enough the locations.xml is there in the root directory, but can't get it open! Maybe I'm missing something in the 'else' section of the code?

Comment: My suggestion was on changing 'use' to 'using', I did not say anything about 'let', pad said that :)

Comment: It seems the file is being written to IsolatedStorage, but on trying to update the file after creation, the document declaration is being added again, throwing an XML exception. Anyone any ideas? I've tried deleting the file before update but I get an IsolatedStorage exception, couldn't access the store :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and thought I'd put the solution up for anyone else having the same issue. 
I needed to load the XML from the store, delete the file and close the 'use' block, Amend the XML, open the file store again in FileMode.Create and save the amended XML back to the store. Here's the solution, and thanks to all who helped me figure it out!:

```
let xname n = XName.op_Implicit(n)
let xdoc (el: seq<XElement>) = new XDocument(Array.map box (Array.ofSeq el))
let xelem s el = new XElement(xname s, box el)
let xstr s = box s


member this.createLocationsFile latitude longitude =
   try                                      
                use store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()                   
                if not (store.FileExists("locations.xml")) then
                     use file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("locations.xml", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store) 
                     let doc =
                        xdoc
                            [xelem "root"
                                [xelem "location"
                                    [(xelem "latitude" (xstr latitude))
                                     (xelem "longitude" (xstr longitude))
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]                   
                     doc.Save(file)

                else
                    use store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
                    use file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("locations.xml", IO.FileMode.Open, store)
                    let docAmended : XDocument = XDocument.Load(file) 
                    file.Close()
                    store.DeleteFile("locations.xml")
                    use file = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("locations.xml", IO.FileMode.Create, store)
                    do
                        docAmended.Element(xname "root").Add(
                            [xelem "location"
                                [(xelem "latitude" (xstr latitude))
                                 (xelem "longitude" (xstr longitude))
                                ]
                            ])

                    docAmended.Save(file)


    with
        | :? IsolatedStorageException as ex -> MessageBox.Show("Error saving file: " + ex.Message) |> ignore
```